# multithreaded server responding to multiple client sessions

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcpclient

Let me explane the situation a bit.
I already wrote a C# multithreaded server, where multiple clients can connect to.
The server holds a dictionary from all clients. Now each client spawns a new instance of a object called ipPhone. To let my server send to the connected client i use the networkstream.write(). that sends to connected client.
However a client can have multiple sessions open. those sessions are saved in a dictionary in the object of ipPhone. From these sessions i save the IP and the port.

Now i was tinking of doing something like this.

```cs
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IpPhoneSession> sessionPair in dicIpPhoneSessions)
{
    phoneSession = sessionPair.Value;
    tcpClient = new TcpClient();
    tcpClient.Connect(sessionPair.ipNumber, sessionPair.portReceiving);
    if (tcpClient.Connected)
    {
        clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        clientStream.Flush();
    }
}
```

however that doesnt work as it seems that doesnt send to the correct port.
Do any of u guys have any idea's on how i can create correct instances of the tcpClient and NetWorkStream to send data to all the sessions of my client.

Comment: Erm...I would start by not re-inventing the wheel. The best off-the-shelf solution I know of is using SignalR with Windows 2012 over Websockets.

Comment: all clients are made in progress openedge so i would like to stick with the current approach.

Comment: Problem with tcp connections to the client is that any number of firewall issues could be blocking you. What have you done to isolate the problem to your code?